# React -> Express: Could Not Proxy Request ONLY after error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, axios

I'm building a React/TypeScript + NodeJS/ExpressJS/Typescript app.

While testing a POST request to create a user, I've discovered that if the email address already exists, an error is sent from the server to the client, which is correct.  But then if I try submitting the POST again, I get this error from the server:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Here's the basic code for the endpoint:

```
// `pool` is coming from `pg`
pool.query('INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, user_name, email, password, last_password, password_salt) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING *', [values.first_name, values.last_name, values.user_name, values.email, values.password, values.password, 'tmp_salt'], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      const response = {status: false, message: error.message};
      res.status(400).send(response);
    }
    res.status(201).send(`User added with user_id: ${results.rows[0].user_id}`);
  });
};
```

Is there something more I'm supposed to be doing when an error occurs?

Final note: In case it's relevant, in my client code's `package.json` there is this line:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

I changed this when I was initially getting CORS errors and several threads I found recommended I add this.  It had solved everything up until now.

Comment: Have you checked that the error is actually handled properly? Sounds like your backend is crashing.

Comment: @super I think you are correct!  I just modified a simple GET endpoint to deliberately fail.  The first time, it sent the error message.  After that, no response ... kind of like above.

Is there something "special" I need to do to do error handling in Express/Node?  Like should I be wrapping everything in `try .. catch` ?

Comment: My bad entirely.  I was too naively following code examples I've been following.  Also, I had thought that `res.status(400).send(response);` was somewhat equivalent to a `return` statement.  It's not.  So you can see from my code above that it's just continuing on to execute the `res.status(201).send...`.  This is where the server app breaks.